# How to separate raster bands in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, raster-calculator

I have a simple model that iterates through folders to collect imagery, mosaics them and clips the mosaic to a study area boundary.  I need to produce an NDVI from the clipped 4-band mosaic "sa11_4band.tif" by incorporating the raster calculator into the model.  The problem I am encountering is that the individual bands do not appear in the raster calculator when I incorporate the raster calculator tool.  How should I separate the raster bands from "sa11_4band.tif" in order to perform the necessary calculation in the raster calculator?:

```
Float("sa11_4band.tif - Band_4"-"sa11_4band.tif - Band_3")/Float("sa11_4band.tif - Band_4" + "sa11_4band.tif - Band_3")
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically with most ArcGIS raster tools if you need to access an individual band you refer to it as an extension to the file name.

For example: `c:\path\to\my\raster.tif\band1`

I haven't had to use this since 9.3, but it definitely worked in the calculator then.  I never used it in a model, but it should work the same since the model is just calling the calculator tool.

Comment: Would this apply given that the 4-band mosaic has not been created until right before the raster calculator is called in the model?

Comment: I'm not sure.  I would think so as long as the file is not in memory.

Comment: Thank you, that saved me! An important tip is to copy the name from your raster instead of type it. Wrong Characters may cause erros in your model.