# How to iterate RGB raster layers in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, arcgis-10.2, map-algebra, rgb

I have an RGB raster that I'm calculating color-based indices from. When I do the calculations manually, I can select a certain band of the RGB raster to calculate.
I need to do the same operations on a folder of rasters, so I use ModelBuilder to iterate the folder, but I don't can't select the individual R, G, B layers from each raster and do calculations on them

I've found [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/48114/how-to-separate-raster-bands-in-model-builder), and have defined the Raster Calculator expression as such, but I receive the following error:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing those mysterious spaces after G:\ are your attempt to make your file path anonymous?

Your output file name is invalid. "cml.tif&_nred" is not a valid file geodatabase name. You cannot have symbols like "." or "&" in the raster name. A valid name would by something like "cml_tif_nred". Have a look at the model only Parse Path tool.

Comment: Indeed, it's a proprietary eponym that I can't disclose.
The & wasn't the problem but the whole xxx.tif_yyy. I used the Parse Path on the tif Name, and it works. Thanks.