# How to Separate Bands Through ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, raster, modelbuilder, composite

Q1: I have a .tiff file containing 365 bands. Each band represents a daily variable. I want to separate each band and save as a single .tiff file. In the end, I want to have 365 individual .tiff files.

Q2: And since these are daily data, is there are a way to make them monthly if you can share your model.

How do I do this?

I am using ArcGIS 10.0.

Comment: How are your bands named? Load the tiff into ArcMap go to the layer properties and under the symbology tab > RGB Composite style what is it saying under Band? Is it something like Band_1?

Comment: As it stands I think your Question is too broad because it contains two questions. Would you be able to edit it so the one which is the most important to you remains, and then research/ask the other one separately, please?

Comment: This would appear to be a duplicate of two previous questions - http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/48114/how-to-separate-raster-bands-in-model-builder?rq=1 and http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/76655/how-to-iterate-through-bands-of-raster-using-arcgis-10-1-modelbuilder?rq=1 There are also a couple of other strongly related questions in the Related category on the right.